# How to configure jest with babel

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm configuring simple project for testing using jest and babel. How do i make them work together ?

I have tried instructions mentioned here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started but couldn't accomplish it.

> abc.test.js

```
import {PI} from "./mathconsts";

describe("tests",()=>{
    test('assert pi', () => {
        expect(PI).toBe(3.14);
    });
});
```

> mathconsts.js

```
export const PI = 3.14;
```

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "simple-testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Project to write simple tests",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "dotenv": "8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "prettier": "1.18.2"
  }
}
```

> babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: {
                    node: 'current',
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

> jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/"
  ],
}
```

> error found:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/tests/abc.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { PI } from "./mathconsts";
                                                                                                    ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
```

How do i make it run ?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your problem by copying and pasting the code you provided above.  do all of the files you mentioned live in the same directory?  what command do you use to run your unit tests?

Comment: `abc.test.js ` and `mathconsts.js` are in a folder called tests. i am using `npm test`

Comment: I am using node version `v10.16.3`

Comment: did you copy the config @DanO

Comment: sandbox is at https://repl.it/repls/CumbersomePhonyRecovery .  download that as a zip, unzip, `npm install`, `npm test`.

Comment: i had used jest --init and it had set `testEnvironment: "node"` in `jest.config.js`. I missed posting that in my question. Thank you @DanO

Comment: when `testEnvironment: "node"` was set it was failing. I have removed it now.